# How can I disable touchpad palm detection on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: touchpad, 17.10, wayland, libinput

As of Ubuntu 17.10 I can no longer configure my touchpad with synclient. The [palm detection feature](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/palm_detection.html) of libinput has an extremely high false positive rate for me and I simply want to turn it off. Thank you for your help.